# Creating Classes inside Namespace C++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a class inside a namespace as it is a parameter for an assignment. however, I am running into some issues with calling function within the namespace, more specifically the operator functions. I have attached the code below.

Point.h

```
#ifndef HW_2_6_POINT_H
#define HW_2_6_POINT_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


namespace udbhavAg
{
           class Point
                   {

           private:
               double m_x; //private variables x & y
               double m_y;

           public:
               Point(); //default constructor
               Point(double inputX, double inputY); //Overloaded contructor.
               Point(const Point &obj); //copy constructor
               explicit Point(double value);
               ~Point(); //destructor
               double X() const; //getter fucntions
               double Y() const;
               void X(const double& input); //setter functions
               void Y(const double& input);
               string toString() const; //to string fuucntion
               double Distance() const; //distance to the origin
               double Distance(Point p) const; //distance between two points
               Point operator - () const; // Negate the coordinates.
               Point operator * (double factor) const; // Scale the coordinates.
               Point operator + (const Point& p) const; // Add coordinates.
               bool operator == (const Point& p) const; // Equally compare operator.
               Point& operator = (const Point& source); // Assignment operator.
               Point& operator *= (double factor); // Scale the coordinates & assign.

                   };

}



#endif //HW_2_6_POINT_H
```

Points.cpp

```
//
// Created by Udbhav Agarwal on 18/05/20.
//

#include "Point.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

namespace udbhavAg
{

        Point::Point() {} //defualt contructor

        Point::Point(double inputX, double inputY) //paramter construcotr, overider
        {
            m_x = inputX;
            m_y = inputY;
        }

        Point::Point(const Point &obj)//copy constructor
        {
            m_x = obj.m_x;
            m_y = obj.m_y;
        }

        Point::~Point()
        {
        } // destructor

        void Point::X(const double& input)  // setting x
        {
            m_x = input;
        }
        void Point::Y(const double& input)  // setting y
        {
            m_y=input;
        }

        double Point::X() const  //returning x
        {
            return m_x;
        }

        double Point::Y() const //returing y
        {
            return m_y;
        }

        string Point::toString() const
        {
            //building the string for output.
            string output = "Point(" + to_string(m_x) + "," + to_string(m_y) + ")";
            return output ;
        }

        double Point::Distance(Point p) const //calculating the distance between 2 points
        {
            double distance = sqrt((pow(p.Y()-m_y,2))+(pow(p.X()-m_x,2)));
            return distance;

        }

        double Point::Distance() const //calculating the distance from origin
        {
            double distance = sqrt((pow(m_x,2))+(pow(m_y,2)));
            return distance;
        }

        Point Point::operator*(double factor) const
        {
            return Point(m_x*factor,m_y*factor);
        }

        Point & Point::operator*=(double factor)
        {
            m_x*=factor;
            m_y*=factor;

            return *this;
        }

        Point Point::operator+(const Point &p) const
        {

            return Point(m_x + p.m_x,m_y + p.m_y);
        }

        Point Point::operator-() const
        {
            return Point(-m_x,-m_y);
        }

        Point & Point::operator=(const Point &source)
        {
            if(this == &source)
            {
                return *this;
            }
            m_x = source.m_x;
            m_y = source.m_y;

            return *this;

        }

        bool Point::operator==(const Point &p) const
        {
            if(this ==&p)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(this->m_y == p.m_y && this->m_x == p.m_x)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Point &p)
        {
            os <<"Point(" << p.X() <<"," << p.Y() << ")\n";
            return os;
        }

        Point::Point(double value)
        {
            m_x = value;
            m_y = value;
        }



}
```

Main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace udbhavAg;
int main()
{
    udbhavAg::Point p = udbhavAg::Point(1);
    cout << p;
}
```

The  compiler is throwing an error : **error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'udbhavAg::Point')
    cout << p;**

Please help. I am unable to understand why I cannot access the << operator here. It works normally when I do not put the Point class in a namespace.

Comment: You don't have a constructor for Point that takes a const int.  You have constructors that accept two doubles and a point type but not an integer, try adding .0 after the 1.

Comment: @SPlatten The exposed error isn't about the constructor. It's about the stream operator `operator<<()`.

Comment: There is a definition of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Point&)` but it's "hidden" in the `Points.cpp`. Add a declaration of it in `Point.h` to fix your issue.

Comment: We see this all the time, newbie learning something new (namespaces in this case), so any problem gets blamed on namespaces. In fact it's just a missing declaration, which would have caused an error with or without namespaces.

Comment: @john On the other hand, I can understand this a bit. When our appl. has new bugs it's nearly impossible to debug everything. (It's way too much code.) So, the first thing I'm thinking about is: What did I add last? (in the hope that that might be the code where the bug has slipped in)

Comment: @Scheff Oh yes, it's completely understandable, especially if you feeling a bit overwhelmed by all the new stuff you are learning. But one of the things you have to learn as a programmer is not to make too many assumptions about your code.

Comment: O.T.: It's bad style (if not a potential source of errors) to do `using namespace std;`, and especially in header files. FYI: [SO: **Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/7478597)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with *Creating Classes inside Namespace*.

This is not what the exposed error is about:

> `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'udbhavAg::Point') cout << p;`

The error indicates that the compiler struggles to resolve the stream operator in

```
    udbhavAg::Point p = udbhavAg::Point(1);
    cout << p;
```

At the first glance, this might be surprising because it is defined in `Points.cpp`:

```
space udbhavAg
{
```

…

```
        ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Point &p)
        {
            os <<"Point(" << p.X() <<"," << p.Y() << ")\n";
            return os;
        }
```

…

```
}
```

However, at the second glance, I realized that there is no prototype in `Point.h` (or any other file which is `#include`d in `Main.cpp`).

So, the only file (aka. translation unit) where the stream operator can be used for `class Point` is the file `Points.cpp`.

To fix this, I would add the prototype to `Point.h`:

```
       std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Point &p);
```

Comment: But why does it work without the namespace?? Technically the  << operator then should not work either way since it does not have a prototype in point.h

Comment: ostream &operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p);

Comment: @UdbhavAgarwal Whether you use it with your own namespace or not, without a declaration (included in each file where you intend to use your `operator<<`), the operator is not known in any other file than the one where it is defined. If you use `using namespace std;`, you can, of course, declared it `ostream &operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p);` (without prefixing each `ostream` with `std::`). (Please, see my other comment why `using namespace std;` is bad.) However, that's not the point of my answer. The point is that you forgot the declaration at all. ;-)